# Calling function from string name within object

Tags: python

I have the following two classes:

```
class A(object):
   def caller(self,name):
      # want to invoke call() here when name="call"

class B(A):
   def call(self):
      print("hello")
```

Given the following:

```
x= B()
x.caller("call") # I want to have caller() invoke call() on the name.
```

I don't want to check the value of `name` I want it to automatically invoke the the given string as a function on self.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use `__getattribute__`

```
class A(object):
   def caller(self,name):
      self.__getattribute__(name)()

class B(A):
   def call(self):
      print("hello")

x= B()
x.caller("call")
```

Output

```
hello
```

Comment: Why not `getattr(self, name)()`?

Answer (score 1):

can also use eval

```
class A(object):
   def caller(self,name):
      eval('self.%s()' % name)


class B(A):
   def call(self):
      print("hello")


x= B()
x.caller("call")
```

output

hello
[Finished in 0.6s]

Comment: Hi Randy is this faster than the above?